# Math.floor VS Math.trunc JavaScript

Tags: javascript, performance, math

### Background

I am making a function that receives a **positive number** and then rounds the number to the closest integer bellow it.

I have been using [`Math.floor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor), but recently I discovered [`Math.trunc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc).

I am aware that both will return the same value, given a positive number, and that they work in completely different ways. I am interested in exploring this behavior.

### Questions

1. Which one is faster ?
2. Which one should I use?

Comment: It is supported in all browsers, I am aware of that. I just wonder how much impact using each one has. That's why I created this questions, but the community seems to not like it :S

Comment: If by “it” you mean `Math.trunc`, you’d be wrong. `Math.trunc` is very new and not supported in every browser.

Comment: @Xufox: You are correct. I discarded IE from my evaluation, but then again I don't really care about it, nor do i think anyone in their perfect sense would :p

Comment: Thank you very much. I feel the same! Thank you for the kindness!

Comment: I made a quick performance test, and the difference per operation on my computer is about 0.00001 milliseconds. In other words, the difference is almost always practically meaningless.

Comment: @Juhana would be nice if we could have that as an answer !

Comment: Here's an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66328506/javascript-round-vs-ceil-vs-floor-vs-trunc/66328507#66328507

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Actually, there is much more alternative ways to remove the decimals from a number. But it's a tradeoff of readability and speed.

Choosing the right one depends on what you need. If you just need to just **remove decimals**, always use `trunc()` or bitwise operators.
The `floor()`, `ceil()` and `round()` are conceptually very different from `trunc()`.

## Math library

You already know these. Always use them in a standard, non-critical code.

```
var v = 3.14; [Math.trunc(v), Math.round(v), Math.floor(v), Math.ceil(v)]
// prints results
```

for different input values you get these results

```
 v        t   r   f   c
 3.87 : [ 3,  4,  3,  4]
 3.14 : [ 3,  3,  3,  4]
-3.14 : [-3, -3, -4, -3]
-3.87 : [-3, -4, -4, -3]
```

`Math.trunc()` **cuts away** *(truncates)* the decimal places.
`Math.round()` **rounds** towards **closest** integer number.
`Math.floor()` **rounds** towards closest **lower** integer number. `3.5 -> 3` `-3.5 -> -4`
`Math.ceil()` **rounds** towards closest **higher** integer number. `3.5 -> 4` `-3.5 -> -3`

---

But this is more fun :)

## Binary operations and [bitwise operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)

If you look at them in the code, it might not be apparent from the first glance what they do, so *don't* use them in normal code. Though in some cases, they might be useful. For example calculating coordinates in a `<canvas/>`. They are much faster, but come with limitations.

### Conceptually, they work this way:

- The operands are **converted to 32-bit signed integers** and thus lose all decimal fractions.

> **ATTENTION:**
> Numbers with more than 32 bits get their most significant (leftmost) bits [discarded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_logical_operators) and the leftmost bit becomes the new sign bit.
>
> ```
> [
>   0b011100110111110100000000000000110000000000001, //  15872588537857
> ~~0b011100110111110100000000000000110000000000001, // -1610588159
>              ~~0b10100000000000000110000000000001, // -1610588159
> ]
> ```

#### Bitwise logical operators

- Each bit in the first operand is paired with the corresponding bit in the second operand. (First bit to first bit, second bit to second bit, and so on.)
- The operator is applied to each pair of bits, and the result is constructed bitwise.

#### Bitwise shift operators

- These operators take a `value` to be shifted and a `number` of bit positions to shift the `value` by.

### truncating

However, when truncating, we always use a `0`, zero, a `false` as a second operand, that doesn't do anything to the original value, except for converting to integer, in these cases:

#### `~`    NOT    `~~v`

#### `|`    OR    `v | 0`

#### `<<`   Left shift    `v << 0`

#### `>>`   Signed right shift    `v >> 0`

#### `>>>`  Zero-fill right shift    `v >>> 0`

```
var v = 3.78;
[ ~~v ,  v | 0 ,  v << 0 ,  v >> 0 ,  v >>> 0 ]
// prints these results

 3.78 : [ 3,  3,  3,  3, 3]
 3.14 : [ 3,  3,  3,  3, 3]
-3.74 : [-3, -3, -3, -3, 4294967293]
-3.14 : [-3, -3, -3, -3, 4294967293]
```

---

## Performance

https://jsperf.com/number-truncating-methods/1

[image]

Comment: Very bad idea.  Large numbers do not go through bitwise operators the way you think.

Try (Date.now()+0.5)>>>0.  Doesn't give you the right answer.

Do not use bitwise operators for flooring a value unless you are doing performance critical work and you know the numbers will always be small.  Graphics work would be an example.

Comment: @JasonMitchell That was actually written in the answer, but I have highlighted it in case more people miss that like you did. Thanks for the hint though.

Comment: In short: use `trunc` ;)

Answer (score 24):

The existing answers have explained well about the performance. However, I could not understand the functional difference between `Math.trunc` and `Math.floor` from either the question or the answers and hence I have put my finding in this answer.

`Math.trunc` rounds down a number to an integer towards `0` while `Math.floor` rounds down a number to an integer towards `-Infinity`. As illustrated with the following number line, the direction will be the same for a positive number while for a negative number, the directions will be the opposite.

```
trunc: towards 0    
floor: towards -Infinity


                   -3      -2     -1      0      1      2      3
-Infinity ... ------+----|--+------+------+------+------+--|----+------ .... Infinity
                         b                                 a
```

**Demo:**

```js
var a = 2.3, b = -2.3;
console.log("\t\t\t" + a + "\t\t" + b + "\r\n" + "Math.trunc: " + Math.trunc(a) + "\t\t" + Math.trunc(b) + "\r\n" + "Math.floor: " + Math.floor(a) + "\t\t" + Math.floor(b));
```

**Output:**

```
            2.3     -2.3
Math.trunc: 2       -2
Math.floor: 2       -3
```

Answer (score 12):

if the argument is a positive number, Math.trunc() is equivalent to Math.floor(),
 otherwise Math.trunc() is equivalent to Math.ceil().

for the performance check this one and the fastest one is Math.trunc

```
var t0 = performance.now();
var result = Math.floor(3.5);
var t1 = performance.now();
console.log('Took', (t1 - t0).toFixed(4), 'milliseconds to generate:', result);
var t0 = performance.now();
var result = Math.trunc(3.5);
var t1 = performance.now();
console.log('Took', (t1 - t0).toFixed(4), 'milliseconds to generate:', result);
```

the result is
Took 0.0300 milliseconds to generate: 3
Took 0.0200 milliseconds to generate: 3

so if the arguments are only positive numbers you can use the fastest one.

Comment: @StevenHansen Looks like a fun challenge to me! How much would you say to be a reasonable value ? 1 million? perhaps 2?

Comment: The benchmarking here only complicates the answer, which itself is perfectly simple.

Comment: Definitely should be the selected answer for this question!

Comment: performing a benchmark on one operation is not enough to prove your point. You have to generate an array of at least a thousand floats to parse then loop on this array with both floor and trunc to compare. like this: https://replit.com/@Freezystem/TruncOrFloor#index.js